# Access phone information

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

im a beginner in android and java programming. currently im trying to develop a apps that scan a QR code and the apps can access information (phone no, IMEI no) and location of it being scanned and send the information and the location into database.

right now i have no idea of how to make the apps access the phone information or location. ( i dnt want to show on the screen, just want to retrieve and send)

do u guys have any idea on what function or activity that i should put inside? or any tutorial to do this? a lil bit of guidance would be really helpful.

thank you.

btw im using zxing to be use as a scanner.

Comment: I would hate my device's information being sent without my knowledge. Regardless of your intentions. This: _i dnt want to show on the screen, just want to retrieve and send_ is a big red flag for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the TelephonyManager class for IMEI , Phone Number and use the LocationManger class for location.

Use this code:

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

// get IMEI

String imei = tm.getDeviceId();

//get The Phone Number

String phone = tm.getLine1Number();